# Run custom script in `Initialize Job` task

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have problem when build a C++ project in azure-pipeline, some `dll` files was access denied.

So I need to run a batch script to stop services which using these `dll`

I was try to run my script at pre-build event in Visual Studio but it execute after `Initialize Job` task, so not work

Are there any way to run script in `Initialize Job`?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you ever get answer for this problem? facing similar issue, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any way to run script in Initialize Job?

I am afraid there is no such way to run script in Initialize Job at this moment. The Prepare job/Initialize Job are some of the predefined work built into the pipeline. We could not add our custom script in or before those jobs.

So, to resolve this issue, we have to find the reason for this error and resolve it.

Generally, this error will most likely make an appearance if your Build and Release Agent goes offline or a build is interrupted due to an issue on the machine itself, and where specific files have been created mid-flight within the Azure Devops directory. When Azure Devops/TFS then re-attempts a new build and to write to/recreate the files that already exist, it fails, and the above error is displayed.

The best resolution is to log in to the agent machine manually, navigate to the affected directory/file (in this example, `C:\VSTS\_work\xxx\xx\.tmp`) and delete the file/folder in question. Removing the offending items will effectively "clean slate" the next Build definition execution, which should then complete without issue.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Also having the same issue. Need to add a pre-execution step before initialize.

Answer (score 0):

I had to solve this exact same problem.  The solution is not ideal, but it works.
I created two pipelines. The first pipeline does any required pre-build steps, like stopping services. The second pipeline is the actual build pipeline, and it gets triggered when the first pipeline finishes. (See the build triggers section in pipeline #2.)